# select statement/subquery in CASE while condition check in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
select sum(COLUMN1) from TABLE1 
where TRUNC(INPUT_DATE) >= CASE WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) <= TRUNC(TO_DATE('02-MAR-22')) THEN 
DATE1 ELSE DATE2 END;
```

Above SQL query working fine, can anyone help me is this possible can i use a subquery 'select date from table2' instead of hard code value TRUNC(TO_DATE('02-MAR-22')).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is only a single row in `table2` then you can use:

```sql
select sum(COLUMN1)
from   TABLE1 
where  TRUNC(INPUT_DATE) >= CASE
                            WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) <= (SELECT date_column
                                                    FROM   table2)
                            THEN DATE1
                            ELSE DATE2
                            END;
```

If there are multiple rows then you will need to correlate on something so that only a single row is returned by the sub-query:

```sql
select sum(COLUMN1)
from   TABLE1 t1
where  TRUNC(INPUT_DATE) >= CASE
                            WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) <= (SELECT date_column
                                                    FROM   table2 t2
                                                    WHERE  t1.something = t2.something)
                            THEN DATE1
                            ELSE DATE2
                            END;
```

or filter so only a single row is returned:

```sql
select sum(COLUMN1)
from   TABLE1
where  TRUNC(INPUT_DATE) >= CASE
                            WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) <= (SELECT date_column
                                                    FROM   table2
                                                    ORDER BY something
                                                    FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY)
                            THEN DATE1
                            ELSE DATE2
                            END;
```

Else you could aggregate in the sub-query (which will always return a single row):

```sql
select sum(COLUMN1)
from   TABLE1 t1
where  TRUNC(INPUT_DATE) >= CASE
                            WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) <= (SELECT MIN(date_column)
                                                    FROM   table2)
                            THEN DATE1
                            ELSE DATE2
                            END;
```

or, combining two previous options:

```sql
select sum(COLUMN1)
from   TABLE1 t1
where  TRUNC(INPUT_DATE) >= CASE
                            WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) <= (SELECT MIN(date_column)
                                                    FROM   table2 t2
                                                    WHERE  t1.something = t2.something)
                            THEN DATE1
                            ELSE DATE2
                            END;
```

Etc.

**YOU** need to work out what your business logic should be and then apply the most appropriate SQL logic in that case.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use a subquery to replace the hard-coded value in your SQL query. Instead of specifying a fixed date in the query, you can retrieve the date from another table using a subquery. Here's an example:

```
SELECT SUM(COLUMN1)
FROM TABLE1
WHERE TRUNC(INPUT_DATE) >=
      CASE
          WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) <= (SELECT TRUNC(DATE_COLUMN) FROM TABLE2)
              THEN DATE1
          ELSE DATE2
      END;
```

In this example, (SELECT TRUNC(DATE_COLUMN) FROM TABLE2) is a subquery that retrieves the date from TABLE2. Make sure to replace DATE_COLUMN with the actual column name containing the date in TABLE2. This way, your query will dynamically use the date from TABLE2 instead of a hard-coded value.

Comment: This will fail if `table2` contains multiple rows.

Comment: You're correct. If TABLE2 contains multiple rows, the subquery in the CASE statement must be modified to return a single value. You can achieve this by using an aggregate function like MAX, MIN, or any other function that makes sense based on your data.

SELECT SUM(COLUMN1)
FROM TABLE1
WHERE TRUNC(INPUT_DATE) >=
      CASE
          WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) <= (SELECT MAX(TRUNC(DATE_COLUMN)) FROM TABLE2)
              THEN DATE1
          ELSE DATE2
      END;